# How solve ILINK32 Error Fatal Out of Space in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, delphi-xe8, c++builder-10-seattle

I'm working with C++ Builder 10. This error also occurs in XE8.

When I am running the project from a Windows 10 development machine for a target OS of OS X (the target is another computer) in *Release mode*, it links and runs fine.

In *Debug mode*, I get the error

> ILINK32 Error Fatal Out of Space

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by going to

Project > Options > C++ Linker > set Target to Debug configuration - OS X platform > set Disable incremental link to true

It now links fine in the debug mode for OS X.